# Symfony4. ParamConverter annotation conflicts injecting a service by autowire

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, autowired, symfony4, doctrine-odm

When I try to use @ParamConverter annotation in a Controller action, I get an error

```
"Cannot resolve argument $company of \"App\\Controller\\ProfileController::top()\": Cannot autowire service \".service_locator.0CrkHeS\": it references class \"App\\Document\\Company\" but no such service exists."
```

I know that such a service does not exist, because I've excluded `Document` path in `services.yaml`. I just need to find a Company document object from Repostiroy.

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php

// src/Controller/ProfileController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Document\Company;
use App\Service\DocumentManager\CompanyManager;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/profile")
 */
class ProfileController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/top/{id}")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Returns top profiles",
     * )
     * @SWG\Tag(name="profile")
     *
     * @ParamConverter("company", class="App\Document\Company")
     * @param CompanyManager $companyManager
     * @return Response
     */
    public function top(CompanyManager $companyManager, Company $company)
    {
        dump($company->getId());exit;
        return $this->handleView($this->view($companyManager->getTopProfiles(), Response::HTTP_OK));
    }

}
```

services.yaml configuration:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Document,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Exception,DataFixtures}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: There is no autowire conflict here.  For whatever reason the param converter is not generating a company object.  I guess you are sure company is a Doctrine entity?

Comment: Yes, Company is a ODM Entity

Comment: There was another recent [question on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269736/symfony-4-autowiring-not-working).  Just for grins you might want to double check and make sure annotations were properly installed.

Comment: And [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) might help as well.

Comment: I solved the issue.

Comment: Consider posting an answer explaining how.  Might be useful for future reference.

Comment: @Cerad, I've posted an answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case somebody else will get same problem.
The problem had nothing to do with autowire conflict. `@ParamConverter` didn't work, because I used mongoDB and Doctrine ODM, not ORM. By default Doctrine ParamConverter won't work for mongo documents.
So I found some information here 
https://matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/symfony2-mongodb-odm-adding-the-missing-paramconverter/

Define a new service in `services.yaml` file:

```
doctrine_mongo_db_param_converter:
    class: Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter
    tags:
        - { name: request.param_converter, converter: doctrine.odm }
    arguments: ['@doctrine_mongodb']
```

Then `@ParamConverter` should work OK now.